# Rendering a selection box for 50 states

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, form

I was creating a Rails form where users have to enter their state. I ended up creating a select tag which is really, really ugly.

I'd like to think there's a better way of writing this.

```
<p>
        <%= f.label :state, "State:*" %></br>
          <%= f.select(:state, [['AL', 'AL'], ['AK', 'AK'], ['AZ', 'AZ'], ['AR', 'AR'], ['CA', 'CA'], ['CO', 'CO'], ['CT', 'CT'], ['DC', 'DC'], ['DE', 'DE'],
          ['FL', 'FL'], ['GA', 'GA'], ['HI', 'HI'], ['ID', 'ID'], ['IL', 'IL'], ['IN', 'IN'], ['IA', 'IA'], ['KS', 'KS'], ['KY', 'KY'], ['LA', 'LA'], ['ME', 'ME'],
          ['MD', 'MD'], ['MA', 'MA'], ['MI', 'MI'], ['MN', 'MN'], ['MS', 'MS'], ['MO', 'MO'], ['MT', 'MT'], ['NE', 'NE'], ['NV', 'NV'], ['NH', 'NH'], ['NJ', 'NJ'],
          ['NM', 'NM'], ['NC', 'NC'], ['ND', 'ND'], ['OH', 'OH'], ['OK', 'OK'], ['OR', 'OR'], ['PA', 'PA'], ['RI', 'RI'], ['SC', 'SC'], ['SD', 'SD'], ['TN', 'TN'],
          ['TX', 'TX'], ['UT', 'UT'], ['VT', 'VT'], ['VA', 'VA'], ['WA', 'WA'], ['WI', 'WI'], ['WV', 'WV'], ['WY', 'WY']]) %>
        </p>
```

Answer (score 5):

you should move the states list outside of view, i.e. to model class.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATES = ['AL', 'AK', 'ID']
end
```

then in view:

```
<%= f.label(:state, "State:*") %></br>
<%= f.select(:state, User::STATES) %></br>
```

This will allow you to reuse states collection anywhere across the application and add easily validate if user hasn't modified the form manually.

*Keeping states in User model is not necessary the best option but it's outside of this question scope*

Comment: Some details: 1) Be consistent with parens on the helper calls. 2) You can drop the `options_for_select`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what rui said, it is usually nicer to present well-formatted data to the user; in this case, "Florida" instead of "FL". Store your STATES as a hash, using [Hash#values](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-values) for the display and [Hash#keys](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-keys) for the internal logic.

Also, considering using [Symbols](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm) for the Hash keys